# Две функции для генерации пароля

Tags: php

Всем привет. Есть функция

```
function generate_password($length=8) {
    $keychars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_:;";
    $randkey="";
    $max=strlen($keychars)-1;
    for($i=0;$i<=$length;$i++)
    $randkey.=$keychars{rand(0,$max)};
    return $randkey;
}
```

Допустим, мы сгенерировали пароль, что-то вроде "vlMqooJ", или "vlMqooJ " (на конце пробел). Далее еще одна функция

```
function htmlspecialchars_decode_php4($str, $quote_style = ENT_COMPAT) {
    return strtr($str, array_flip(get_html_translation_table(HTML_SPECIALCHARS, $quote_style)));
}
```

и из указанного выше пароля, можно получить шифрованный пароль "c684f43dc0c37b8d0fd58f5270929a016ead9ade"

Прошу объяснить, как получить с помощью вышеуказанного пароля, вышеуказанный шифрованный пароль?

Comment: > далее еще одна функция

Она просто экранирует спецсимволы HTML.

> c684f43dc0c37b8d0fd58f5270929a016ead9ade

Какой-то двадцатибайтовый хэш. Вы предлагаете хэш-функцию угадать? Такую длину, например, SHA1 выдает.

Comment: Скажу так: вполне вероятно, что это SHA1 от пароля с солью.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> прошу объяснить, как получить с помощью вышеуказанного пароля, вышеуказанный шифрованный пароль?

Взять пароль и зашифровать его так, как самому хочется!

Вариант то один, не более.

можно взять **md5();**

> хэш-функцию угадать

если угадать то можно еще и пра-пра-пра-правнуков поднапрячь.

Comment: @frank, сегодня на хэшкоде  организовал олимпиаду по угадыванию паролей и хэш-функций по хэшу  )

Comment: по ходу дела да!